# Traefik on windows 2016 unable to connect to Docker

Tags: windows, docker, traefik

Trying to get Traefik to work on Windows 2016 Server.  It is unable to connect to the local docker daemon and gives the following error.  Any ideas?

```
traefik_1  | time="2018-05-17T11:21:25-04:00" level=error msg="Failed to retrieve information of the docker client and server host: error during connect: Get http://192.168.32.1:2376/v1.24/version: dial tcp 192.168.32.1:2376: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."
```

My daemon.json file contains: `{"graph": "E:\\Docker"}`

Here is the output from `c:\>docker system info`

```
Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 10
Server Version: 17.06.2-ee-10
Storage Driver: windowsfilter
 Windows:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
 Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Default Isolation: process
Kernel Version: 10.0 14393 (14393.2214.amd64fre.rs1_release_1.180402-1758)
Operating System: Windows Server 2016 Standard
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 2.386GiB
Name: dockerServer
ID: QOKM:O5QE:XOMZ:YNQN:JGT2:XAWN:DIUG:3K3H:M725:CADH:G6NE:Y5RK
Docker Root Dir: E:\Docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Here is the output for the api version request:
    PS C:\Windows\system32> invoke-webrequest http://192.168.32.1:2376/v1.24/version

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {"Platform":{"Name":""},"Components":[{"Name":"Engine","Version":"17.06.2-ee-10","Details":{"ApiVersion":"1.30","Arch":"amd64","BuildTime":"2018-04-27T00:54:58.493613431+00:00","Experimental":"false",...
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Api-Version: 1.30
                    Docker-Experimental: false
                    Ostype: windows
                    Content-Length: 633
                    Content-Type: application/json
                    Date: Tue, 22 May 2018 11:53:35 GMT
                    Server: Docker/17.06.2-ee-10 ...
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[Api-Version, 1.30], [Docker-Experimental, false], [Ostype, windows], [Content-Length, 633]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : System.__ComObject
RawContentLength  : 633
```

Comment: Can you post the launch parameters of the Docker daemon? (the flags on what's currently running, at least). If you have a `daemon.json`, can you provide that too?

Comment: I modified the question to include the information that you requested.  Any way to see the current running parameters than 'docker system info'?

Comment: The answer at https://superuser.com/q/415360/139751 might be useful. May I ask how you chose `192.168.32.1:2376` to access the Docker daemon?

Comment: I used the section on traefik.toml from [here](https://stefanscherer.github.io/how-to-run-encrypted-windows-websites-with-docker-and-traefik/) then also used ip config to find the HNS Internal NIC.

Comment: There is only the run-service parameter passed to dockerd.  Using Process Explorer: C:\Program Files\Docker\dockerd.exe --run-service

Comment: Alright, I have some ideas - just need a bit more information. On the host that is running the daemon, can you try `curl http://192.168.32.1:2376/v1.24/version`?

Comment: I had to make changes to the deamon.json file first in order to allow unsecured access on windows.  See the question for the output.

Comment: Does `curl` to that same address work within the container?